# Installing 32-bit Java on VM

Tags: java, virtual-machine

I am trying to install 32 bit Java on my virtual machine, however I don't see any 32 bit versions available in Azure and I tried to use one from Java official website, I get following error.

-bash: .: JavaSetup8u241.exe: cannot execute binary file

The codes I have only run on 32 bit Java, so it is imperative that I use 32-bit version only.Any solutions? Thank you.

Comment: Why are you running a windows installer? I don't know that a 32-bit JRE is available anymore, and based on your requirement for a 32-bit JRE I can only assume you are attempting to invoke native windows 32-bit DLLs. You'll need Windows for that.

Comment: What makes your codes (not sure what you mean by "codes") dependant on 32 bin java?

Comment: bash and exe ! Agreed with @Elliot hope you are not trying to run windows installer on a linux VM.

Comment: Everyone, thanks for your quick responses!                                        @ElliottFrisch: I have legacy codes which only work with 32 bin Java, and I have VM(Ubuntu 18.04) which will need 32 bin Java installed on it. I am very new to Java and the only task I need to accomplish for this project is to run those codes on linux VM. Any suggestions please? How do I  install Java 32 bin on linux VM? I really appreciate responses.

Comment: *I have legacy codes which only work with 32 bin Java* Yes. But **why**? Do they use native libraries? Did they ever work in Linux? Are you sure?

Comment: Yes, they worked in Linux and they do use native libraries and that's why when they use them using java 64, you get an error telling this is not compatible with java 64 (All this information has been fed to me, I am still trying to figure out how to run them even in Java 64). Any pointers on that? I really appreciate you being so helpful.

Comment: The world has moved on from 32-bit code (the 4GB memory limitation was a big one). I have looked at AdoptOpenJDK and at Amazon Coretto; I still don't think anyone is maintaining a 32-bit JDK for any platform besides Windows. In short, the decision to target 32-bit native code with Java was a bad one, the consequences of which are just now hitting you. Your code targets a platform that is unsupported and unmaintained, time to replace the code.

Comment: You are so helpful! I will start looking at native dictionaries used in 32 bin Java, and would ask pertinent question on how to replace them. Thanks :)

Comment: Found a 32 bit version [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk8-downloads.html). You want "jdk-8u241-linux-i586.tar.gz" - but seriously, it was hard to find; and I doubt it will be supported for much longer.

Comment: Thanks for providing me with the Java 32 bin version. This is what I see:             tejal@EfficiencyCalculator:~/java32$ ls
jdk-8u241-linux-i586.tar.gz  jdk1.8.0_241
tejal@EfficiencyCalculator:~/java32$                                                                
How do I run Java? because whenever I type java -version after this, I get an error: tejal@EfficiencyCalculator:~/java32$ java -version
Command 'java' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install default-jre
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jre-headless

Comment: I am clueless as to why I am getting this, since I already did:                              
$ tar zxvf jdk-8u241-linux-i586.tar.gz 
Thank you so much!

Comment: @Tejal123 Follow the official [installation instructions](https://java.com/en/download/help/linux_install.xml#install).

Comment: Then `export JAVA_HOME="/directory/you/justmade/in/last/step"` and `export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH`

Comment: Hi Elliot,I did following steps:Installed tar.gz file and it created directory jdk1.8.0_241
Then used echo $JAVA_HOME to see the path, got an empty path, so set the path using 
tejal@EfficiencyCalculator:~/java32$ export JAVA_HOME=/java32/jdk1.8.0_241 and then did 
tejal@EfficiencyCalculator:~/java32$ export PATH=$JAVA_HOME
then did 
tejal@EfficiencyCalculator:~/java32$ cd jdk1.8.0_241/
tejal@EfficiencyCalculator:~/java32/jdk1.8.0_241$ java -version
Command 'java' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install default-jre
   Did I make any mistake? Thanks!

Comment: These are the files I see in jdk1.8.0_241 folder: tejal_mulay@EfficiencyCalculator:~/java32/jdk1.8.0_241$ ls
COPYRIGHT                           bin             man
LICENSE                             include         release
README.html                         javafx-src.zip  src.zip
THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME-JAVAFX.txt  jre
THIRDPARTYLICENSEREADME.txt         lib

Comment: `export JAVA_HOME=$HOME/java32/jdk1.8.0_241` and `export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH`

Comment: You missed `$HOME` and you missed `/bin:$PATH` respectively.

Comment: Thanks for your help Elliott, this definitely worked :)